# Getting an 'Undefined index' error for 'Same as Above' field

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a form field with items

```
    <label for='usrad_resi'>
Residential Address </label><input id='usrad_resi' name='usrad_resi' type='text' required>
```

Upon clicking a 'same as above' checkbox I managed to get the value in another textbox:

```
    <label for='co_addrcheckl'>
        Address </label><input type='checkbox' name='co_addrcheck' id='co_addrcheck' onSelect='sameAbove()'> Same as Above
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for='usrad_co_addr'>
        C/O Address </label><input id='usrad_co_addr' name='usrad_co_addr' type='text' required>
```

The javascript for this is:

```
   var loc = document.getElementById('co_addrcheck');
   var home = document.getElementById('usrad_co_addr');
   var post = document.getElementById('usrad_resi');
   loc.onclick = function(){if(loc.checked)
   {    
        home.disabled = true; home.value = post.value;}
   else
   {home.disabled = false; home.select();}}
```

My problem is that when trying to access $_POST['usrad_co_addr'] using php i get an 'Undefined index: usrad_co_addr' error. This happens irrespective of whether the 'usrad_resi' field is empty or not.
Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: <form  name='add_dealer' method='post'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set that field to disabled in javascript. Disabled fields are not submitted. If you want to keep behaviour and still submit the value as well you could create a hidden field and also copy the data there.

Answer (score 0):

What hoppa said is true. Disabled fields are not submitted. What you can do is use a `hidden` object to send this data.

```
<input id='usrad_co_addr' type='text' required />
<input id='usrad_co_addr_h' name='usrad_co_addr' type='hidden' />
```

And in your Javascript:

```
   var loc = document.getElementById('co_addrcheck');
   var home = document.getElementById('usrad_co_addr');
   var home_h = document.getElementById('usrad_co_addr_h');
   var post = document.getElementById('usrad_resi');
   loc.onclick = function(){
       if(loc.checked)
       {    
           home.disabled = true; 
           home.value = post.value;
       }
       else
       {
           home.disabled = false; 
           home.select();
       }
       home_h.value = home.value;
    }
```